# How to include a file after git clone in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml

After cloning a repo in gitlab ci yml file I want to access a file from the cloned repo as in the following code

gitlab-ci.yml file

```
include:
    - project: my-project
      ref: mybranch
      file: file1.yml

before_script:
    - echo "Before script setup"
    - git clone -b mybranch --single-branch my-project.git
```

Now in file1.yml of my-project I want to include a file

file1.yml

```
include:
   local: ./my-project/template/common.yml
```

it is saying local file does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes are simple, they just paste the content of the file you are including into your current GitLab CI file.

in your case it will look like:

```yaml
include:
   local: ./my-project/template/common.yml

before_script:
    - echo "Before script setup"
    - git clone -b mybranch --single-branch my-project.git
```

and you do not have this file in your local repository.

### Solution

As you can only include a file once, i recommend to not use includes over multiple levels. What if you have a `file2.yml` which is also including `common.yml` - and you need both? this will also result in an error. I suggest to take the convention route and force people to always include `common.yml` if they also include another file from your template project

In you case you are only talking about one project, you do not need to have such a fancy include structure with `project`, `ref` and `file`. It is enough to use the `local` directive. like

```yaml
include:
  - local: file1.yml
```

same for the include within the file. I am not sure what `my-project` is in your case, i assume it is the same repository. Than you do not need to take care of the `git clone` this will be done by the GitLab CI job automatically and all files will be available within the same directory.

#### template project

sometimes you want to reuse scripts in other projects, than i would simply suggest to create a template project and use it like this.

```yaml
 include:
    - project: templateproject
      ref: mybranch
      file:
        - common.yml
        - file1.yml
```

If your common.yml is about triggers, just call it triggers, and try to split functionality into separate files. I discovered that it is a good practice to provide several building blocks, and let the projects themselves combined them - with one default to take a look at.

We provide seperate includes for:

- triggers
- script blocks
- utility methods, like docker login etc.

the projects will never receive a whole finished job (except security and quality tools) - but have to arrange them like:

```yaml
include:
   - project: templates
     file:
       - triggers.yml
       - script.yml

job1:
   stage: build
   extends:
     - .trigger # a job named like this in triggers.yml which contains rules
     - .build # a job named like this in script.yml for building

job2:
   stage: test
   extends:
     - .trigger # a job named like this in triggers.yml which contains rules
     - .test # a job named like this in script.yml for building
```

This way the project does not only contain an include, but also more information about the build, and you can imagine what is going on, by looking at the CI file. There is little indirection, and as long as you keep the naming simple and descriptive, you can increase readability.